# JavaScript timer jump ahead

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys please check this code, first part from innit, second is my timer function. Thanks alot!

I set up a timer for 15min. Save the time in cookies and read saved time on init

```
var cc=readCookie("agreement");
var ct=readCookie("secondsleft");

if (ct == null || ct == '') {
    secondsleft = 15*60;
} else {
    secondsleft = parseInt(ct);
}

myInterval = setInterval(bingoTimer,1000);
```

Can anyone see why after refresh this code jumps to 0:13?

```
function bingoTimer() {
    secondsleft--;

    if (secondsleft < 0) {

    } else {
        var minLeft = parseInt(secondsleft / 60);
        var secLeft = secondsleft - minLeft * 60;
        var timeLeft = " " + minLeft+":" + secLeft;
        var timeCookie = createCookie("secondsleft", timeLeft);
        $('#timer').html(timeLeft);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe parseInt parses the first integer value that it can find in the string. In your example you save the time int this format: "minLeft:secLeft". I think parseInt will only parse the minLeft part and ignores the rest of the string after the ':'. So your 13 minute and something seconds is parsed into 13 seconds in secondsleft = parseInt(ct);

Try changing createCookie("secondsleft", timeLeft) to createCookie("secondsleft", secondsleft.toString()).

Comment: Awesome Thank you! Nice start!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C86Su/25/)

Your problem was:

```
var timeCookie = createCookie("secondsleft", timeLeft);
```

timelLeft is a string("14:59"), so after parse int it was converted to 14, and -1 you got "0:13". You need to put value in seconds:

```
var timeCookie = createCookie("secondsleft", secondsleft);
```